# Is there a way in cornerstone to inject html by url?

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to add additional html into my cornerstone theme which is available by some url. For example, is there any helper like `{{loadHtml http://example.com/mypage }}` ?

**Update**

I do not need js implementation. I do not need to insert component or other theme specific file. I do not need an iframe. The html lives on another server which serves custom app. So I have an app and I need to inject html by some url from my app.

Comment: Could you share a little more info about the use case? Are you trying to render a component (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/development-quickstart/rendering-html-with-ajax) or more like an iframe?

Comment: @KarenWhite I updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks @FreeLightman , I don't think there's going to be a way to do this without JS because there isn't a handlebars helper registered to Stencil that injects external HTML. But, this tutorial might give you a way forward: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/conditional-logic-examples/dynamic-content-rendering#dynamic-content_dynamic-tabs